# Eye of Cthulhu boss text but he never spawned

Tags: terraria-console

I have seen the Eye of Cthulhu boss text, but he never spawned. Also, I waited about 20 Terrarian days and he still didn't spawn. Is it a glitch?

Comment: Were you underground? The Eye will only spawn if you're on the surface

Comment: At what time did you spawn him? If you spawned him right before dawn he might have flown away.

Answer (score 1):

To spawn the Eye of Cthulhu you must be over ground, and you should spawn it at the start of the night. If you spawn it at the end of the night, it will fly away be you see it.

Other than that, it may possibly be a glitch - you should restart your console and try again if you think it is.